# Sistemas de ecuaciones diferenciales

Tags: python

Estoy realizando en Python el sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales pero no entiendo bien como hacer para que aparezca la solución.

```
%matplotlib inline 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy 
import numpy as np 
from scipy import integrate 

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Function('y')

a=-5
b=-1
c=4
d=-1

    def ODE(a,b,c,t):

        f = a*x+b*y
        g = c*x+c*d
         init_printing(use_unicode=True)
             return f,g




sympy.Eq(x(x).diff(t), f)
sympy.Eq(y(x).diff(t), g)
```

Tengo algo mal en el código? y como lo podría solucionar ?

Comment: De entrada el código no está bien indentado (mira la definición de ODE). Por otro lado nunca invocas ODE, y en las dos últimas líneas tienes variables no definidas (t, f, g). (Nota al margen: no sé usar sympy para resolver ecuaciones diferenciales, los fallos señalados son  más bien de sintaxis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es dificil saber el tipo de ODE que estas intentando resolver. Si añades una imagen .tex de tu ODE ayudaría mucho.

Sim embargo, me da la impresion que estas intentando resolver ODE acopladas, en tal caso aqui encuentras un ejemplo muy sencillo de como solucionarlo

```
# Very simple example showing how to solve ODE systems

# 1. Import libraries
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 2. Preliminaries. The ODE system
# dy/dt = v
# dv/dt = -g

# 3. Include the ODE in a function


def ode(x, t):
    v = x[0]
    g = x[1]
    dydt = v
    dvdt = -g
    return(dydt, dvdt)


# print(ode([1, 2], 1))          # Just for test the function
# 4. Set up the initial conditions
x0 = [1, 1]                      # Initial values of the functions
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)      # Time

# 5. Solving the ODE
sol = sci.integrate.odeint(ode, x0, t)

# 6. Plot the solution
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0])           # Plot v
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1])           # Plot g
plt.show()
```

La idea general, es que debes definir tu sistema de ODE en una función, donde las variables de tu sistema deben estar en forma de vector definidas en la función (ve el punto 3 del ejemplo). Luego de ello, asigna unas condiciones iniciales (punto 4) y finalmente resuelve el sistema `sci.integrate.odeint`

Saludos,